# Python print to csv in iteration, save rows without line spaces

Tags: python, iterator, export-to-csv

Hello I will save this output to a csv file after iteration, print is ok, but csv not.
Below are the print output

```
1580933840499281920 2022-10-14 14:49:34+00:00 illiabogdanov en RT @alexstubb: Dear @elonmusk, the war in Ukraine is about life and death, freedom and control, democracy and autocracy. 

1580933840448540672 2022-10-14 14:49:34+00:00 lies_das de RT @KPosmik: Wir haben uns entschieden, diese Szene von der Demo der #AfD #b0810 zu zeigen, um mit dem Vorurteil aufzuräumen, die #Luegenpr…
1580933839823679488 2022-10-14 14:49:34+00:00 JaviMac10 en RT @dim0kq: 0. I admire the actions of SpaceX of enabling StarLink service in Ukraine. It is a true game changer for Ukrainian army in the…
1580933839748145155 2022-10-14 14:49:34+00:00 LovelyLassSandy en @elonmusk Please consider continuing your Starlink platform in Ukraine! Can you work out a way to make this a charitable contribution for which you receive substantial tax breaks. Do not leave these families disconnected! Starlink has been a God to Ukraine!`
```

Python code:

```
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.id, tweet.created_at, users[tweet.author_id].username, tweet.lang, tweet.text)
# Make a new file
    with open("test_file.csv", "w") as my_file:
            writer = csv.writer(my_file)
            writer.writerows(tweet.id, tweet.created_at, users[tweet.author_id].username, tweet.lang, tweet.text)
```

error:

```
 writer.writerows(tweet.id, tweet.created_at, users[tweet.author_id].username, tweet.lang, tweet.text)
TypeError: writerows() takes exactly one argument (5 given)
```

Comment: "takes exactly one argument (5 given)". I would try combining all those five strings into one string, and use that new string in writer.writerows()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
with open("test_file.csv", "w") as my_file:
    writer = csv.writer(my_file)
    for tweet in tweets:
        writer.writerow([tweet.id, tweet.created_at,users[tweet.author_id].username, tweet.lang, tweet.text])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide writer.writerows(someiterable).

Iterable is an object which can be looped over or iterated over with the help of a for loop. Objects like **lists, tuples, sets, dictionaries, strings, etc**. are called iterables. In short and simpler terms, iterable is anything that you can loop over.

So it should look like this.

```
newUser = [tweet.id, tweet.created_at, users[tweet.author_id].username, tweet.lang, tweet.text]
writer.writerows(newUser)
```

Comment: File "search_recent_tweets.py", line 49, in <module>
    writer.writerows(newUser)
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int

Comment: Can you post the updated code

Comment: Nvm I think I see it above.